# How to instantiate constant as the result without the error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

a function returns an array of [result, error]

Right now I am instantiating the constant as the array:

```
const [result, error] = function
```

How do I instantiate only the result element like this:

```
const result = function
```

Comment: Why do you want to? If a function returns an error value, you really shouldn't be ignoring it.

Comment: Your code does not instantiate an array. It *decomposes* the returned array into two separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably extract it directly from your function
`const result = function().result`

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the first element returned by the function, it can simply be

```
const [result] = function();
```